# Domains in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've just been reading ['Give us Real Domains!'](http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#Domains) on SQL Server MVP Erland Sommarskog's SQL Server Wishlist.

I was thinking of trying out `CREATE TYPE` with bound rules but was alarmed to learn that this is a deprecated feature.

Does SQL Server have anything resembling support for domains that is worth using? Are bound rules are worth using, considering that at least one SQL Server MVP is keeping it alive?

P.S. Don't forget to vote for [Add CREATE DOMAIN command](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=124645) ;)

Comment: the feature request is from 2006, with no comment from MS. clbuttic

Comment: @devio: Yes. So? Isn't the point that if 55 gazillion stackoverflow users vote for it today then it will be in a new release tomorrow, or have I misunderstood how things work in a democracy such as Microsoft? ;)

Comment: Sorry, the SQL division is too busy sucking the soul out of 'Oslo' to be bothered adding real features

Comment: You never know: folding 'Osolo' into SQL Server could result in proper domain support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that domain support currently found in SQL Server is not fit for purpose. Best to wait until the `CREATE DOMAIN` command is added ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I'd venture a guess, data types with embedded behavior (rules, checks, constraints) are better fit for CLR UDTs. You are seeing this already in SQL Server 2008, where some new data types come as built-in CLR types like [geography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) and [geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx).