# Storing custom values in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

How do I store custom values in place of data types for the column.
I have a Table named as 'Orders' in which a column named as 'OrderStatus' and it's purpose will be to store the Status of the Order. For example R=Rejected, S=Sent, T=Returned.

I am very new to databases and design...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you don't really need a custom data type, you just need a foreign key to a table with all of your statuses in it.

Your `OrderStatus` table would look like:

```
id           int           PK NOT NULL, IDENTITY
code         char(1)       NOT NULL
description  varchar(100)  NOT NULL
```

(edit:  note, as Martin pointed out in a comment on another answer, the surrogate `id` key isn't entirely necessary, but it allows flexibility for easily changing the `code` without having to update the data that refers to it)

Your `Order` table would then have a foreign key to this table:

```
order_status_id  int      FK NOT NULL
```

Comment: I have created this new Table as you mention and created relationship as well between Orders and OrderStatus. So if I want to retrieve the order status then it will be the char(1) which will return the character right? or do I need to set the Values or something?

Comment: One more Q. Is it possible to implement a restriction on the char data type so that user can only insert allowed values of R=Rejected, S=Sent, T=Returned?

Comment: Yeah you'll just join on this table and select `code` from it.  The easiest way to restrict what codes can be entered is just simply not allow anyone write/modification permissions to that table.

Answer (score 2):

The 'correct' answer is to use Standard SQL-92's `CREATE DOMAIN`. Sadly, SQL Server doesn't support it yet. If you would like to see support you can vote for it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124645/add-create-domain-command).

SQL Server has its own `CREATE TYPE` syntax but when I last looked I declared them not fit for purpose. If anyone disagrees, please post an answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577136/domains-in-sql-server) :)

This leaves two viable choices: a table with a foreign keys or `CHECK` constraints. The rule of thumb is that if the set of domain values is small and stable (e.g. the [ISO 5218 sex codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218)) then use `CHECK` constraints, otherwise prefer a table with foreign keys.

Comment: Interesting. Did not know about CREATE DOMAIN.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that.

```
OrderStatus OrderStatusCode
----------- ---------------
Rejected    R
Sent        S
Returned    T
```

Later, when you've got more 'design' under your belt, you go with a lookup table.

Comment: why wait?  no time like the present to learn about normalization

Comment: @daniel: I suppose so, but normalization is a beast to get right and might take more time than he has. Also, Jasmine might have some fun getting the joins right... :)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to normalize, which means creating a table called ORDER_STATUS with the approved values in there, minimally with a schema like:

```
ORDER_STATUS(id number auto increment, code character, meaning varchar)
```

and then relate ORDERS to that table in a column called order_status_id, which would be a foreign key that would not be null.

Comment: Introducing a surrogate key in place of a character code is not normalization. It would only be a normalization issue if they actually repeated the code and meaning in the `Orders` table.