# Postgres FK declaration references customer name rather than type?

Tags: postgresql, types, foreign-keys, pgadmin

I don't use Postgres much (I used to use other DB's) so recently I was viewing a db in pgAdmin and saw an odd schema syntax which I can't find anything on the documentation and want to know a bit about it:

So I see this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  table1_id serial NOT NULL,
  table2_fk_id t2_id NOT NULL, -- what is this line?
  ...
  CONSTRAINT fk_table2_chm FOREIGN KEY (table2_fk_id)
      REFERENCES table2 (t2_id_col) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

What is that marked line above? It seems like the foreign key col rather than specifying int/int8 it is specifying a custom name `t2_id`?

Whereas in `table2` pk column which is being referenced above is of type `serial` and is labeled `t2_id_col`.

Is that some exotic syntax? Or something related to pgAdmin?

Comment: `t2_id` could be a user defined type or a domain.

Comment: Did you add `**` or is that in the original code? Because that would just be a syntax error ...

Comment: no sorry that was just to highlight the line, I have removed it to avoid confusion

Comment: If it a user defined type, I can not find a definition for it and wouldn't make sense as foreign key it references is a serial in table2

Comment: The foreign key constraint would still work if `t2_id` is a domain with `int` as base type. And please fix the misleading example in the question.

Comment: Yes spot on, your right, found the domain definition for it using an integer

Comment: It's not exotic, just unfamiliar to you. `CREATE DOMAIN` has been part of SQL standards since at least SQL-92, and every major SQL dbms except MySQL supports it.

Comment: IIUC microsoft still refuses to support domains, driving customers into UDT-hell: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1577136/905902 Oracle seems to have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell for sure, run:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_type
WHERE  typname = 't2_id'
```

If `typtype` is `d` it's a domain, created with [`CREATE DOMAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdomain.html).
Or in pgAdmin just check the list of domains in the "Object browser".

And yes, this is *somewhat* related to pgAdmin, since it does you the courtesy of displaying a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column as such. `serial` is not an actual type, the underlying type is `integer`. So your domain type must be based on `integer` as well to allow the foreign key, which requires matching base types. Details:
[Safely and cleanly rename tables that use serial primary key columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)